# Unable to write data from TCP port to HDFS using Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, streaming, hdfs, apache-spark

I am trying to stream data from a TCP port and load the data into HDFS using Spark-Streaming.

The files are are getting created in HDFS, but they are all empty. But the Spark Streaming console shows reading of the data from the TCP port.

I tried this in Spark 0.9.0, 0.9.1 and 1.0 using the Scala-Shell in CDH-5.  I did a  'nc -lk 9993' in a anothe terminal to stream the data.

Below is the code, please let know how this issue could be resolved. Thanks.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import StreamingContext._

val ssc8 = new StreamingContext("local", "NetworkWordCount", Seconds(1))
val lines8 = ssc8.socketTextStream("localhost", 9993)

val words8 = lines8.flatMap(_.split(" "))


val pairs8 = words8.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts8 = pairs8.reduceByKey(_ + _)

wordCounts8.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://Node1:8020/user/root/Spark8")

wordCounts8.print()

ssc8.start()
```

Appended ---------------------------------------

I have provided the logs and the HDFS files below -

```
HDFS  Output Files
--------------------

-rw-r--r--   3 user1 user1          0 2014-06-26 09:19 /user/user1/SparkV/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 user1 user1         0 2014-06-26 09:19 /user/user1/SparkV/part-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 user1 user1          0 2014-06-26 09:19 /user/user1/SparkV/part-00001




Spark-Shell Console Log
---------------------


-------------------------------------------
Time: 1403789836000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(f,3)
(fsd,2)
(sdf,2)
(fds,1)
(sd,3)

14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1403789836000 ms.1 from job set of time 1403789836000 ms
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(8) called with curMem=327, maxMem=286339891
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1403789836000 stored as bytes to memory (size 8.0 B, free 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1403789836000 in memory on localhost:49784 (size: 8.0 B, free: 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block input-0-1403789836000
14/06/26 09:37:16 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1403789836000 already exists on this machine; not re-adding it
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1403789836000
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(15) called with curMem=335, maxMem=286339891
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1403789836200 stored as bytes to memory (size 15.0 B, free 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1403789836200 in memory on localhost:49784 (size: 15.0 B, free: 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block input-0-1403789836200
14/06/26 09:37:16 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1403789836200 already exists on this machine; not re-adding it
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1403789836200
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(8) called with curMem=350, maxMem=286339891
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1403789836400 stored as bytes to memory (size 8.0 B, free 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1403789836400 in memory on localhost:49784 (size: 8.0 B, free: 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block input-0-1403789836400
14/06/26 09:37:16 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1403789836400 already exists on this machine; not re-adding it
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1403789836400
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(9) called with curMem=358, maxMem=286339891
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1403789836600 stored as bytes to memory (size 9.0 B, free 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1403789836600 in memory on localhost:49784 (size: 9.0 B, free: 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block input-0-1403789836600
14/06/26 09:37:16 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1403789836600 already exists on this machine; not re-adding it
14/06/26 09:37:16 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1403789836600
14/06/26 09:37:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(14) called with curMem=367, maxMem=286339891
14/06/26 09:37:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1403789836800 stored as bytes to memory (size 14.0 B, free 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1403789836800 in memory on localhost:49784 (size: 14.0 B, free: 273.1 MB)
14/06/26 09:37:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block input-0-1403789836800
14/06/26 09:37:17 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1403789836800 already exists on this machine; not re-adding it
14/06/26 09:37:17 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1403789836800
14/06/26 09:37:18 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 6 blocks
14/06/26 09:37:18 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1403789838000 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

At first glance my guess is you should try local[4] instead of just local so Spark can schedule more tasks.

Comment: Thanks.I tried using both local[2] and local[4], but still it did not write into HDFS.

But -

1. Previously the wordcount was not getting displayed on console, now it is.
2.Now along with the _SUCESS file inside the directory, the part-* files are also getting created - but all are empty.
                                                                  Also - I am not using the method ssc8.awaitTermination() . And, when I use ^D or terminate the netcat function, still there is no use. Am I missing something here?  Also, I have appended additional logs and HDFS output files to original post.

Comment: I'm glad we made some progress, is there any reason why you are not using awaitTermination()? My guess in that case would be that your driver program might be exiting early.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to use awaitTermination() once the start() method is specified, streaming logs begin in the console and I cannot call the method awaitTermination(). If I open a new terminal, open the spark shell and call the var.awaitTermination() function, it does not do anything. Pls assist if my understanding is not correct or if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: If you run application entirely inside of the cluster by submitting your application driver using the submission client. then following command should work    **./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <driverId>**

Answer (score 0):

## try with

wordCounts8.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://Node1:8020/user/root/Spark8", "log")

==========
or

## put some timestamp after "Spark8"

wordCounts8.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://Node1:8020/user/root/Spark8" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString())

==========
It is work for me with spark 1.3 , see if it is work for you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try running

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://Node1:8020/user/root/Spark8
```

(The hadoop command might be different for you. For me, I had to access it with /a/bin/hadoop, but this is specific to your setup)

See if this returns:

```
cat: `hdfs://Node1:8020/user/root/Spark8': Is a directory
```

If it does, then as you said in your comments, you should be able to see a _SUCCESS file as well as some part-* files in that directory.

At this point, my problem was solved. But you seem to have additional issues with writing to your HDFS.

As to why your files were still empty, I'd recommend switching to Spark1.4.0, since that may work a lot better with CDH5.4. Also, if you're having trouble with the HDFS permissions, you'll have to execute

```
hadoop dfs -chmod -R 0777 /your_hdfs_folder
```

in order to have write access.